# subgroup of $C_{16} \times C_{30}$,and C is the cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

(1)How many cyclic subgroups are in the group  $C_{16} \times C_{30}$,and C is the cyclic group

(2)How many subgroups are in the group $C_{16} \times C_{30}$,and C is the cyclic group

my opinion is  $C_{16} \times C_{30} \cong C_{2} \times C_{240}$.

so subgroups of $C_2$ are$C_2 $ and ${1}$,the number of subgroups of $C_{240}$ is 20 ,
so the number of subgroups is $2 \times 20 =40$

if (m,n)=1,then $C_{m} \times C_{m} \cong C_{mn}$ is cyclic group ,so ${1} \times C_{m}$ is cyclic group ,

the number of these is 20,

$C_{2}\times C_{m}$ is cyclic group only $ m=1,3,5,15$

but,  $C_{1} \times C_{2} =C_{2} \times C_{1}$

so the number of cyclic group is $3+20=23$

I don't know my answer is true or not

Comment: Do you know the decomposition theorem of finite abelian groups?

Comment: Tell us how many you could see; we can help you by pointing out if you missed any. It is expected you make an effort to solve the problem yourself  and share  any partial results of your efforts, instead of merely posting "Prove this ..."

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* By the Chinese remainder theorem, $C_{16} \times C_{30} \cong C_{2} \times C_{240}$.

Answer (score 0):

The essential fact in this case is that the group $G$ has the Klein Vierergruppe $C_2 \times C_2$ as a subgroup, resulting in the fact that $G$ has three elements of order $2$. With this in mind we will count the number of cyclic groups. First of all we have those who have odd order, there are four of them :$$C_1, C_3, C_5 \text{ and } C_{15}$$. Then there are those whose order is even with a squarefree factor $2$: there are three for each of them since we can obtain a generator by multiplying a generator of odd order with one of the tree elements of order $2$, this gives us twelve groups: $$C_2, C_6, C_{10}\text{ and } C_{30} $$ Let $a,b$  be the respective generators of $G = C_2 \times C_{240}$ then the remaining cyclic subgroups are the groups which order have order with non squarefree factor  $2$, there are two of each of them : those who are a subgroup of $C_{240}$ and those obtained by the previous ones by multiplying their generator with $a$ this gives $24$ cyclic subgroups : $$ C_4, C_8, C_{12},C_{16},C_{20},C_{24}, C_{40},
C_{48}, C_{60}, C_{80},C_{120}\text{ and }  C_{240}$$ As a conclusion : we have $4 + 12 + 24 = 40$ cyclic subgroups. The non cyclic subroups are easier to count since the are the direct products $C_2 \times H$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $C_{240}$ with odd order so there are $$16 of them.

Conclusion : *$G$ has $40+16 = 56$ subgroups*